# How to select EmberJS elements with puppeteer

Tags: ember.js, automated-tests, puppeteer, cucumberjs

Okay, I'm currently stuck.  I'm trying to implement CucumberJS and Puppeteer on an EmberJS solution.

I've got a emberjs button:

```
{{#ao-button data-test-button-view-related-payments-requests="true" isFluid=true size="large" type="primary" action=(route-action 'viewRelatedRequests' upload)}}<span class="ao-button__label" >View Related Payment Requests</span>{{/ao-button}}
```

and I included an HTML attribute: data-test-button-view-related-payments-requests="true"

When I attempt tp select it:

```
await this.page.click('[data-test-button-view-related-payments-requests="true"]');
```

I get:

```
Error: No node found for selector: [data-test-button-view-related-payments-requests="true"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you use `ember-test-selectors`? They are automatically removed from production builds. That's kind of the idea.

Comment: I'm not - I'm trying to use CucumberJS and Puppeteer.  The Ember-Test-Selectors add-on is really meant for the ember unit test framework.  I'm working on a BDD UI test framework.

Answer (score 1):

Custom data-* attributes must be enabled in order to pass them to a component. This is done by extending the component and then adding attribute bindings. See [this section](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_adding-other-attributes-including-data-attributes) of the Guides. Example:

```
import LinkComponent from '@ember/routing/link-component';

export default LinkComponent.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle', 'lang']
});
```

Comment: I saw that example as well in the documentation guide.  I guess I'm looking for guidance on ember component data- attribute binding.

Comment: Did you try extending the component like it shows in this example? What happened?

Comment: I got it to work - I put a delay (await delay(4000);) - I assume it wasn't finished rendering.  I wonder if there is a way to wait until render is complete?

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan there is a didRender hook in components that might work. Timeouts will cause test suite problems. I suggest ember concurrency if you have to keep the timeout. Also for future debugging, using breakpoints and inspecting the DOM or `return pauseTest` in testing can help a lot

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not sure how to access the didRender hook outside of ember's runtime.  How can I access this with puppeteer calls?

Comment: Are you trying to do the click from a testing environment? What kind of test? The need for a timeout makes it sound like there are other async things happening outside of usual Ember patterns. You might also want to ask on the Ember Slack test channel too